# Viber - Video Hardwere not found - Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: hardware, webcam, viber

I have installed Viber (Rakuten Viber) 7.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on HP laptop 4PN36EA#BED. The audio is working perfectly, the video from the other side is working while on my side the camera is not recognized even more in settings for Video: "Hardware not found". Interesting is that if I start the Ubuntu application "Cheese" the camera is working without problems.

So: How to tell the Viber that there is a camera in this PC, that the drivers are installed and how could Viber use it?

Many thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enable camera permission.
[image]

Comment: where is this permission thing?

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti go to Ubuntu Software -> type Viber -> click on installed programm -> and then you find Permissions

Comment: I have ubuntu-mate and thee software center is blocked and cannot add it

Comment: sudo snap connect viber-unofficial:camera

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 19.04 I have the same issue. Moreover, software center couldn't find Viber breaking into endless loop. However in "installed" tab there was a Viber-mtd. After

> sudo snap connect viber-mtd:camera
>   Viber starts see the camera.

Comment: error: snap "viber-mtd" has no plug named "camera"

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Viber in 20.04 using Ubuntu Software and the results were miserable: it would not recognise the USB camera, despite allowing it via the Permissions. I uninstalled it and installed the proper deb package and it works perfectly. Conclusion: avoid snap installation.

Comment: What is "the proper deb package"?  I don't see this software anywhere in Ubuntu repositories: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=viber&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10. Viber 13.3.1 installed directly from https://www.viber.com/en/download/.  Video broadcast works with internal webcam but not  USB webcam.  With menu Tools > Modify Audio & Video, I can select and see USB webcam image so it can't be a permission problem.  Not sure it is the same bug however.

Comment: Cheese OK.  Viber 10.8.0 (on Mac OS) with similar hardware OK.